# Closure tree through association?

Tags: ruby

I'm using the closure tree gem to provide a hierarchy for organizations.

Each organization can have many users.

```
class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users

  acts_as_tree
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :org
end
```

Given a set orgs, and a user that belongs to them, how to I return the orgs they user belongs to with hierarchy?

```
o1 = Org.create!
o2 = Org.create!
o3 = Org.create!
o4 = Org.create!
o1.children = [o2,o3]
o3.children = [o4]

u = User.create
o3.users << u

u.some_org_hierarchy_meth

> [o3 => [ o4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can satisfy your needs with a flat list, calling `user.org.self_and_descendants` will return an array that contains first the user’s Org, then this org’s descendants, and so on. The array is sorted by generation level.

If the order of the orgs and their hierarchy are important, closure_tree can return a [hash tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree#nested-hashes). Call `user.org.hash_tree`. It will return nested [OrderedHash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash.html) objects, keys being the orgs, values being OrderedHashes of their children.

The [closure_tree gem documentation](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) has examples for both methods.